# Foliation of $\mathbb R^n$ by connected compact manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, fibre-bundles, fibration

Does there exist a smooth nontrivial fiber bundle $p: F \hookrightarrow \mathbb R^n \to B$ such that $F$ and $B$ are connected manifolds with $F$ compact? "Nontrivial" here means the fiber $F$ is not a point.

Comment: The title says "foliation", the body of the question says "fibration": Which one do you actually mean?  The question about foliations was asked earlier (one and half ears ago) at MSEhttps://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842525/folitaion-of-mathbb-rn-by-compact-leaves

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There does not, even if you don’t require the fiber and base to be manifolds (or even connected, just that $F$ is not a single point).  See

Borel, Armand; Serre, Jean-Pierre,
Impossibilité de fibrer un espace euclidien par des fibres compactes,
C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 230 (1950), 2258–2260.

Answer (score 14):

On the other hand, if you only mean "foliation" as in your title, and not "fibration", then there is Vogt's foliation of R^3 by circles! (But it is not C^1, only differentiable).
Vogt, Elmar, "A foliation of R3 and other punctured 3-manifolds by circles",
Publications Mathématiques de l'IHÉS, Tome 69  (1989), p. 215-232
http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1989__69__215_0/

Comment: And it appears that the existence of a $C^1$-foliation by circles is an open problem.

Comment: Thank you Moishe, I should have added that Vogt's foliation is not C^1. It's corrected.